# Customize android-target-tooltip overlay for Android

Tags: android, tooltip

I am trying to customize the overlay and the background color of the tooltip library https://github.com/sephiroth74/android-target-tooltip. But I am unable to understand how the custom attribute works.

As there is no withStyleId attribute in the builder function as well.

Please help me if someone has implemented such customization in this library.

Thanks!!!